# Infinite Scrolling is not working while fetching data

Tags: reactjs, react-infinite-scroll-component, react-infinite-scroll

I'm trying to fetch the news in my infinite scrollbar but it is not working properly and every time I run this code my laptop get stuck.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
export class News extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    country: "us",
    pageSize: 8,
    category: "general",
  };
  // static propTypes={
  //     country:PropTypes.string,
  //     pageSize:PropTypes.number,
  //     category:PropTypes.string
  // }
  capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: [],
      loading: true,
      page: 1,
      totalResults: 0,
    };
    document.title = `${this.capitalizeFirstLetter(
      this.props.category
    )} - News Monkey`;
  }
  async updateNews() {
    //this is the function to update news
    try {
      this.setState({
        loading: true,
      });
      let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=01b1a8fe6ec74a02b41f4e0050d4d394&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
      let data = await fetch(url);
      let parsedData = await data.json();
      this.setState({
        articles: parsedData.articles,
        loading: false,
        totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("something is not working");
    }
  }
  async fetchMoreData() {
    // this.setState({
    //     page: this.state.page + 1,
    // });
    // this.setState.page+=1;
    this.state.page += this.state.page;
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=01b1a8fe6ec74a02b41f4e0050d4d394&page=${this.state.page}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      articles: this.state.articles.concat(parsedData.articles),
      loading: false,
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
    });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.updateNews();
  }
  handlePrev = async () => {
    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page - 1,
    });
    this.updateNews();
  };
  handleNext = async () => {
    this.setState({
      page: this.state.page + 1,
    });
    this.updateNews();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center">
          {" "}
          News Monkey - Top {this.capitalizeFirstLetter(
            this.props.category
          )}{" "}
          Headlines{" "}
        </h1>
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.articles.length}
          next={this.fetchMoreData}
          // style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }} //To put endMessage and loader to the top.
          inverse={true} //
          hasMore={this.state.articles.length !== this.state.totalResults}
          loader={<Spinner />}
          scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
        >
          <div className="container my-4">
            <div className="row">
              {this.state.articles.map((element, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="col-md-4 my-4" key={index}>
                    <NewsItem
                      title={element.title ? element.title.slice(0, 40) : ""}
                      description={
                        element.description
                          ? element.description.slice(0, 40)
                          : ""
                      }
                      urlToImage={element.urlToImage}
                      author={element.author}
                      date={element.publishedAt}
                      url={element.url}
                      source={element.source.name}
                    />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default News;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the function where you have to change url and make page+1 in url and update state after the url. This is an async function so before state is getting updated url is getting created so update like below:

Also You can refer the exact code here link, please like the comment it it helps: https://github.com/anshikaagrawal29/NewsMonkeyApp-React/blob/main/src/Components/News.js

```js
fetchMoreData = async () => { 
 
    let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=${this.props.apiKey}&page=${this.state.page+1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    
    //fetch is used to get the data from api
    this.setState({page : this.state.page + 1})
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    //This is how we set the state variable
    this.setState({
      // concat function : Combines two or more arrays.
      articles: this.state.articles.concat(parsedData.articles),
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults
    });
  };
```